# Double dollar sign in code breaks indentation

Tags: bug, markdown, mathjax

For example, if I have Markdown like:

```
    $$
    $$
```

Then both lines should have the same indentation (zero), but they don't. It renders as:

```
$$
    $$
```

I suspect this is somehow caused by MathJax.